# Generic method in C# containing reference to member of generic type (class)

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I try to write generic method and try to express constrain about member of generic type.

```
private async Task<T> FindOrAdd<T>(DbSet<T> dbSetOfT, string name) where T : class
    {
        var result = await dbSetOfT.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Name = name);
        return result ?? new T { Name = name };
    }
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: well if you want to filter by name you need at least an interface or parent class that has a Name field. Alternatively there would be a rather unsafe method of using reflection to get the name, but this would lead to errors if the T hast no Name field.

Comment: Also, you can't create a new instance of T unless you constraint that it has a parameter-less constructor. You can do this with "where T : class, new()"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible using a interface.
I have added the interface to the criteria of `T` and also added `new()` To make `New T` possible

```
private async Task<T> FindOrAdd<T>(DbSet<T> dbSetOfT, string name) where T 
: class,IName,new()
{
    var result = await dbSetOfT.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Name == name);
    return result ?? new T { Name = name };
}

public interface IName
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Comment: `c => c.Name == name`

Comment: @JeremyLakeman you are right copy and paste from the original question, i have edited the answer